# In python, how to quickly set the value of each row of a 2 dimensional array by condition on the corresponding element of a one dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays

For instance, I have the following `numpy` arrays:

```
a = numpy.array( [ [ 1 , 3 , 3 ] , [ 2 , 5 , 5 ] , [ 3 , 7 , 7 ] ] )
b = numpy.array( [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] )
```

I want to write a piece of code that will emulate:

```
a[ a == b ] = 0
```

which the output will be:

```
[ [ 0 , 3 , 3 ] , [ 0 , 5 , 5 ] , [ 0 , 7 , 7 ] ]
```

How to achieve this by not applying a `for` loop. Here it is just an example, in real reality the arrays are very large and `for` loop takes too much time to run.

Comment: What are the values in `b`? Are they rows or columns numbers?

Comment: I mean the first element of the first row of a equals the first element of b. The first element of the second row of a equals the second element of b. The first element of the third row of a equals the third element of b. Use these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array( [ [ 1 , 3 , 3 ] , [ 2 , 5 , 5 ] , [ 3 , 7 , 7 ] ] )
b = np.array( [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] )

def f(b, a):
    return np.where(a == b, 0, a)

print(np.array([*map(f, b, a)]))
```

which gives:

```
[[0 3 3]
 [0 5 5]
 [0 7 7]]
```